# C compiler is not generating valid assembly output

Tags: c, assembly, kernel

I am writing a simple kernel in C and ASM(to call assembly instructions generated by C compile). I am following this excellent articles from osdev.org. After read an kernel written in assembly and compiled and executed, it was worked fine, I see the kernel.bin running on qemu, fantastic. But I want really to write it in C. I found [an example](http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/view/writing-a-simple-c-kernel) in same web page.

I compiled it and tried run the kernel.bin on qemu but I get "boot failed" from all devices: hard disk, floopd and CD-rom.  then I disassembled the kernel.bin generated by ks.o (kernel.asm assembled using nasm) and kernel.o (kernel.c assembled using gcc) assembled to bin file using the ld. The kernel.bin:

http://pastebin.com/Y0pLFvij I can't see my string or any instruction to assembly write my string on video.

The C code that generate it:

```
#define WHITE_TXT 0x07 // white on black text
unsigned int k_printf(char *message, unsigned int line);
void k_clear_screen();

k_main() 
{
    k_clear_screen();
    k_printf("Hi!\nHow's this for a starter OS?", 0);
};

unsigned int k_printf(char *message, unsigned int line) // the message and then the line #
{
    char *vidmem = (char *) 0xb8000;
    unsigned int i=0;

    i=(line*80*2);

    while(*message!=0)
    {
        if(*message=='\n') // check for a new line
        {
            line++;
            i=(line*80*2);
            *message++;
        } else {
            vidmem[i]=*message;
            *message++;
            i++;
            vidmem[i]=WHITE_TXT;
            i++;
        };
    };

    return(1);
};

void k_clear_screen() // clear the entire text screen
{
    char *vidmem = (char *) 0xb8000;
    unsigned int i=0;
    while(i < (80*25*2))
    {
        vidmem[i]=' ';
        i++;
        vidmem[i]=WHITE_TXT;
        i++;
    };
```

and the `assembly` that call it:

```
[bits 32]

[global start]
[extern k_main] ; this is in the c file

start:
  call k_main

  cli  ; stop interrupts
  hlt ; halt the CPU
```

the link.ld

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")

ENTRY(start)

SECTIONS

{

  .text  0x100000 : {

    code = .; _code = .; __code = .;

    *(.text)

    . = ALIGN(4096);

  }

  .data  : {

    data = .; _data = .; __data = .;

    *(.data)

    . = ALIGN(4096);

  }

  .bss  :

  {

    bss = .; _bss = .; __bss = .;

    *(.bss)

    . = ALIGN(4096);

  }

  end = .; _end = .; __end = .;

}
```

and the makefile:

```
bin:
    nasm -f aout -o ks.o kernelbase.asm 
    gcc -Wall -c -o kernel.o kernel.c    
    ld -T link.ld -o kernel.bin ks.o kernel.o 
run1:
    qemu kernel.bin

clear:
    rm -f *.o

cbin:
    rm -f *.bin
```

and the kernel in pure assembly, disassembled: http://pastebin.com/Bkvkq3YQ 
that worked fine for me, and I can see the instrutions to write on video.

My OS: Ubuntu 10.4
Compiler: gcc
Assembler : NASM

Where am I wrong?

Comment: There is code missing. The C code cannot possibly compile in that form.

Comment: No, the C code is does not compile too well. Also, there are warnings.

Comment: What do you think the difference is between C converted to asm then assembled and "really write it in C".  Certainly gcc does this, you compile a c program it compiles to asm, then calls the assembler and linker for you.  No difference (so long as you use the same compiler/assembler/linker, compile options, and linker script.

Comment: @NiklasB.: how to remove this warnings?

Comment: @dwelch:I know that there no difference, all is assembly. When I say "Written in C" is uses C syntax and C compiler to make assembly.

Comment: @Jack: Compiling this C code *gives me compile time errors*. It does not even *succeed* in compiling, how should it possibly result in what you want?

Comment: @dwelch: I think by "really write it in C" he meant that he'd really like to use C to write his OS, rather than x86 assembly (which is somewhat sensible).

Comment: How are you setting up your stack? If you declare `k_clear_screen` and `k_printf` as `static inline` or append:`__attribute__ ((__always_inline__))`, what happens? Regardless, the linker options are clearly resulting in 4096 zero bytes starting at 0x100000.

Comment: @NiklasB.: I don't get any errors, only some warnings like `kernel.c:6: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’`. what error you are getting?

Comment: @Jack: nvm, the syntax error was a missing curly brace at the end. Still, leaving out the return type of a function is exceptionally bad style. Especially because you probably want `void` there instead of `int`.

Comment: Can PCs boot directly to 32-bit code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to do that tutorial and the code failed too. Finally I did this:

Compile both files for 32 bit:

```
nasm -f elf32 ks.asm -o kernelbase.o
gcc -m32 -c kernel.c -o kernel.o
```

And link:

```
gcc -m32 kernelbase.o kernel.o -o Kernel.bin
```

After a while I found out that I don't get any errors by using gcc for linking.

Hope I helped :-)

Comment: what is -c flag on nasm options? I removed it and was compiled successfully and I can see valid assembly output. another question: have you tried run kernel.bin? I tried run it with qemu kernel.bin but I get something like "boot failed" cannot found any device, then I liked it using ld: `ld -T link.ld -o kernel.bin kernelbase.o kernel.o `, looks like a progress, it know the and show "Booting from hard disk" but never start the kernel. Thanks very much, @XCoder.

Comment: Sorry "-c" was my mistake I compiled it without the "-c". So far I haven't test it. (no time) ;)